# Passing a value from one form field to others in an expandable form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically expandable form that at the top I want the user to be able to set the default value that would be copied throughout the form. I have been trying an onchange event for the date field but it does not update the date fields that follow.

I have tried to troubleshoot the code by changing element id's and names w/o any success.

```js
function updateDate(value) {
  document.getElementById("date").value = value;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML for the initial field -->
<div class="col-sm-auto">
  <input type='date' class='form-control' onchange="updateDate(this.value)" id='default_date' name='default_date' value='' data-toggle="tooltip" data- placement="top" title="The date the shift started." />
</div>
<!-- HTML for the field that it is supposed to be updating -->
<div class="col-sm-auto">
  <input type='date' class='form-control' name='date' id='date' value='' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="The date the shift started." />
</div>
```

I expected it to set the value of any date fields with the id='date' but it did nothing that I can see.

## ###More Code###

Here is the rest of the HTML on the page. It still does not update the initial set of form fields. However, as pointed out in comments it does update any additional fields added by clicking the 'Add Another Responder' button.

```
<!-- HIDDEN DYNAMIC ELEMENT TO CLONE -->
<!-- you can replace it with any other elements -->
<div class="form-group dynamic-element" style="display:none">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-auto"></div>

  <!-- Replace these fields -->
    <div class="col-sm-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <input type='date' class='form-control' name='date' id='date' value='' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="The date the shift started."/>
    </div>

<!--These DIVs are used for additional for fields. I removed the code for ease of troubleshooting-->        
    <div class="col-sm-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-auto">
    </div>

    <!-- End of fields-->
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger delete1">Delete Row</button>
    </div>
  </div><hr>
</div>

<!-- END OF HIDDEN ELEMENT -->

<div class="container" style="display:inline">
  <form class="form-horizontal" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
      <!-- Form Name -->
      <legend class="title">Enter Times</legend>

      <!--Default Form Values-->

          <div class="container col-sm-auto border-bottom pb-3 pt-3 bg-info">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-md-auto column1"><h5>Set your default values:</h5>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <input type='date' class='form-control' onchange="updateDate(this.value)" id='default_date' name='default_date' value='' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="The date the shift started."/>
                </div>

                <!--Additional Form fields removed for troubleshooting-->

                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
<!-- End Default Values -->        

          <div class="dynamic-stuff">
            <!-- Dynamic element will be cloned here -->
            <!-- You can call clone function once if you want it to show it a first element-->
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success add-one" role='button'>Add Another Responder</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" name="timesubmit" id="timesubmit">Submit Times</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>


<!--php removed to troubleshoot HTML & JS-->

<script>

    //Clone the hidden element and shows it
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dynamic-element').first().clone().appendTo('.dynamic-stuff').show();
  attach_delete();
});       

$('.add-one').click(function(){
  $('.dynamic-element').first().clone().appendTo('.dynamic-stuff').show();
  attach_delete();
});
//Attach functionality to delete buttons
function attach_delete(){
  $('.delete1').off();
  $('.delete1').click(function(){
    console.log("click");
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
  });
}

//Set Default Variables On Change
    function updateDate(value){
    document.getElementById("date").value = value;
}

//Make Table Rows Clickable
    $(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".table-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems working!!!

Comment: I edited your question and created a working snippet from the example code you posted. The snippet above seems to be working as you were hoping, so it may be that you have some additional code not posted with your question that is causing an issue.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I believe you are correct @benvc. After you guys said it is working I did a little more trouble shooting. The initial form loads with the first line and does not update when I edit the field. BUT if I expand the form it does set the value for date. I will attach the additional code...

Comment: I can just remove the JS that makes the first row appear on load. But I'd rather not. Ideas?